# javascript: Update the DOM only when the result is ready

Tags: javascript, css, api, async-await, dom-manipulation

I have some api endpoint.

one returns all server details (https://dnscheck.io/api/serverDetails/)
others are `server specific` endpoint. (https://dnscheck.io/api/query/?id=2&type=A&hostname=test.com) for each server_Id(which I got from `serverDetails` endpoint), I have to call each api endpoint.

what I have done is.

I loop over the results array (which I got from `serverDetails` endpoint)

and for each iteration of loop, I call each endpoint for getting the ip.

loop:

```
 for (const [index, item] of data.entries()) {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://dnscheck.io/api/query/?id=${item.id}&type=${query.type}&hostname=${query.host}`
    );
    const result = await res.json();

    renderResult(result, item, index);
  }
```

render-function:

```
const renderResult = (result, data, index) => {

  const ip = document.querySelector(`.ip-address${index + 1}`);
  ip.innerHTML = result.answers[0].address;

};
```

In this way, results are displayed in the DOM in a sync way. (one after another)

But, what I want is, update the dom with the result, as soon as the result is ready.

what can I do?

Comment: `But, what I want is, update the dom with the result, as soon as the result is ready.` you mean when all result**s** of your fetch requests that you issue in your `for` loop are ready?

Comment: not like that. look at how there search results are come.
they do not come in sync way.  I want this.

`https://www.whatsmydns.net/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `await`, as that blocks the `for` loop and orders the results. Use `.then()` instead.

```
for (const [index, item] of data.entries()) {
  fetch(
      `https://dnscheck.io/api/query/?id=${item.id}&type=${query.type}&hostname=${query.host}`
    ).then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => renderResult(result, item, index));
}
```

Comment: Recommend adding error handling so there aren't unhandled rejections, but absolutely, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do them in parallel by using `map` on the array and using `fetch` within. You can know when they've all finished by using `Promise.all` to observe the overall result:

```
await Promise.all(
    data.entries().map(async (index, item) => {
        const res = await fetch(
            `https://dnscheck.io/api/query/?id=${item.id}&type=${query.type}&hostname=${query.host}`
        );
        // You need to check `res.ok` here
        const result = await res.json();
        renderResult(result, item, index);
    )
);
```

Note that `Promise.all` will reject its promise immediately if any of the input promises rejects. If you want to know what succeeded and what failed, use [`allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) instead:

```
const results = await Promise.allSettled(
    data.entries().map(async (index, item) => {
        const res = await fetch(
            `https://dnscheck.io/api/query/?id=${item.id}&type=${query.type}&hostname=${query.host}`
        );
        // You need to check `res.ok` here
        const result = await res.json();
        renderResult(result, item, index);
    )
);
// Use `results` here, it's an array of objects, each of which is either:
// {status: "fulfilled", value: <the fulfillment value>}
// or
// {status: "rejected", reason: <the rejection reason>}
```

---

About my "You need to check `res.ok` here" note: this is unfortunately a footgun in the `fetch` API. It only rejects its promise on *network* failure, not HTTP errors. So a `404` results in a fulfilled promise. I write about it [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html). Typically the best thing is to have wrapper functions you call, for instance:

```
function fetchJSON(...args) {
    return fetch(...args)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`); // Or an error subclass
        }
        return response.json();
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to use the async keyword in the `Array#map` callback. Also, you need to `return renderResult` EDIT: my bad, no return needed.

Comment: The `async` was missing but the `renderResult` doesn't have to be returned - it doesn't seem to return anything.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew - that's embarrassing. :D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :(

Comment: Thanks for the *second* edit @CherryDT! Goodness, I'm not on my game today, am I?